# Xcode 4.5 won't detect an iPhone 5 device with iOS 6.1.4 . while earlier it was working fine

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, xcode4.5, iphone-5

Xcode 4.5 won't detect an iPhone 5 device with iOS 6.1.4 . I tried changing deployment target to lower but still no help

Comment: Had the device been reset ? Is it enabled for development ?

Comment: no device is not ben reset. how to enable for dev? i said it as workin fine . only now breeding trouble

Comment: In Xcode > Window > Organizer > Devices >YOUR DEVICE

Answer (score 0):

You need Xcode 4.6.x to debug with iOS6.1.x
[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Versions_compare_table)

Comment: How come it ran with 4.5 earlier. Just yesterday it was running fine with xcode4.5 . same xcode version .. same device ...